# Fill values in column until certain value in another by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table where is user id and the duration of the trip in hours.

```r
data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
      user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
   `trip.(h)` = c(0, 0.02, 170, 0.07, 12, 3, 90, 550, 1)
)
```

| user_id | trip (h) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.02 |
| 1 | 170 |
| 1 | 0.07 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 90 |
| 1 | 550 |
| 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

Now I would like to add a column with a trip id for each person. Trip id should change for each person (unique **user_id** ) if any value in column **trip** is longer than 155 hours. I would do it with a loop, but the dataframe contains 12 columns and 5.7m rows so it would be highly ineffective. Is it possible to do it columnwise with dplyr? Since I have multiple user_id, I would firstly group by user id and then maybe do it with mutate()? Maybe with fill()?

Also thought of counting >155h trips for each person and then assigning 1:n() elements to each trip, but it also seems a little far fetched

This is the desired output:

```r
data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
      User.id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
   `trip.(h)` = c(0, 0.02, 170, 0.07, 12, 3, 90, 550, 1),
      trip_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)
)
```

| User id | trip (h) | trip_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.02 | 1 |
| 1 | 170 | 2 |
| 1 | 0.07 | 2 |
| 1 | 12 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 90 | 2 |
| 1 | 550 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: No, just whenever the trip is over 155h it is a start of a new trip

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you can, please review the following on how to provide a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Knowing how to do this will prove beneficial in your questions to come!

Comment: Yes, thank you, very good point you showed! I will keep this in mind for the next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cumsum` like below

```
df  %>% 
  group_by(User_id)  %>% 
  mutate(trip_id = cumsum(trip>155)+1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but it's not meant to be cumulative. Just when a value in column trip appears bigger than 155 then it should be next trip e trip_id +1

Comment: @BrigittaRebane Did you try my solution?

Comment: Ok, it worked in my test data! Thanks! I guess the trick what I missed in your solution was that the cumsum() is around the condition too!

Answer (score 0):

trip (h) will be read as trip..h. in R

```
your_data %>% 
  mutate(flag_new_trip = as.integer(trip..h. > 155)) %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  mutate(trip_id = cumsum(flag_new_trip)+1)
```